# Yahoo Fantasy Sports API

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-api

Is anyone still using the Yahoo Fantasy Sports API?  I had an app that worked last year, have not changed my code at all, and now it is returning a 500 internal error when I try to run it.

I used to test things through the YQL Console, but that is no longer available.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Anyone know how to make authenticated requests on that site above?

My feeling is that Yahoo has just discontinued support for their FantasySports API, I will have to look for other solutions I think.

Wondering if anyone else out there used this API previously and is or is not still having success with it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use C# core and Yahoo's API.  Huge thanks to [this guy](https://www.yogihosting.com/implementing-yahoo-oauth-2-0-in-csharp-and-asp-net/)

1. Get your api key etc from yahoo.

Make a controller action that redirects to the request URL something like this:

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
            yo.yKey = {your Yahoo API key};
            yo.ySecret = {your Yahoo API secret};
            yo.returnUrl = {your return URL as set in the API setup, example "https://website.com/home/apisuccess"};

            var redirectUrl = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=" + yo.yKey + "&redirect_uri=" + yo.returnUrl + "&response_type=code&language=en-us";
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

This will send you to a site that authenticates with Yahoo.  Upon successful authentication it is going to send you to your redirect site with a string parameter called code, in the example it would be home/apisuccess, so that controller action should look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApiSuccess(string code)
        {        
            List<string> msgs = new List<string>();     //This list just for testing
            /*Exchange authorization code for Access Token by sending Post Request*/
            Uri address = new Uri("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token");                

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] headerByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_yKey + ":" + _ySecret);
            string headerString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(headerByte);
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + headerString;

            /*Create the data we want to send*/
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            data.Append("client_id=" + _yKey);
            data.Append("&client_secret=" + _ySecret);
            data.Append("&redirect_uri=" + _returnUrl);
            data.Append("&code=" + code);
            data.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");

            //Create a byte array of the data we want to send
            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            // Set the content length in the request headers  
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            // Write data  
            using (Stream postStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }
            // Get response
            var vM = new yOauthResponse();
            string responseFromServer = "";
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    msgs.Add("Into response");
                    // Get the response stream  
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    msgs.Add(responseFromServer.ToString());
                    vM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yOauthResponse>(responseFromServer.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msgs.Add("Error Occured");
            }
            ViewData["Message"] = msgs;
            return View(vM);
        }
```

Note that I used a json deserializer of this model, but you can do whatever you want with the response to get the data you need out of it.   This is my json model:

```
public class yOauthResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
        public string accessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "xoauth_yahoo_guid")]
        public string xoauthYahooGuid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "refresh_token")]
        public string refreshToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
        public string tokenType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expires_in")]
        public string expiresIn { get; set; }
    }
```

Once you have that data, the main thing you need is the access_token, and use it as follows in a controller action:

```
//simple code above removed
    var client = new HttpClient()
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri({your request string to make API calls})
                };
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                   //do what you will with the response....
                }
                //rest of simple code
```

Hopefully this helps someone somewhere.  Happy coding!